# Filtering specific column in Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

[On Angular's website](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) there are quite a lot of examples that show how to implement one of their Material tables, including tables with sorting, pagination and filtering. I want to extend one of their examples, the table with filtering, to have a second filter that, for example, specifically filters the `Weight` column. This doesn't seem to have a straight forward solution, so I don't really know where to start. I have found [an example that filters a specific column](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-table?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), but I don't understand how it works or why it works like it does.

Comment: The reference you have is for AM2 beta.  The code will probably be quite different in 5.0.0-rc0, the current version.  There were some significant changes to the table api.  I don't have an answer for the new version, at least yet.